# A normal distribution with a mean defined by a vector

Tags: vectors, normal-distribution, means

I am currently reading a paper that talks about having a vector to define the mean of a normal distribution. The paper can be found [here](http://snap.stanford.edu/nipsgraphs2009/papers/xiang-paper.pdf).

It is equation 2 that I am concerned with whereby the mean of the normal distribution takes a 'Similarity vector'.

I am wondering if this is in fact a Multivariate Normal Distribution?

Comment: $w^Ts$ is a scalar, as is $v$ by the looks of it so I don't think this is multivariate.

Comment: Yes! I am with you! That's what I missed!